# Using Certutil to manage CA, show certificates for requester name/id and revoke

Tags: powershell, certificate-authority, certutil

I am searching for another way to manage my CA.

I wrote a powershell script, which allows me to show all my certificates for a specified requester name or request id and to revoke those certificates.

Is it possible to do this in `certutil`?
I can't find any information about the request id or the requester name

Comment: Why not PowerShell?

Comment: Im working in a high security department. Our consultant told me that the powershell pspki module is based on c# or c++ (i dont know) and to install this on our CA is not secure. thats why i want to change to certutil.

Comment: It is based on C# and is open source, I don't see any security issues here. CA automation with certutil is a real pain. And you don't need to install pspki module on CA server because it supports remote connections to CA.

Comment: how do i use the pspki cmdlets without the module? I havent seen a other solution than installing the pspki module